# Grails Spring Security 2.0 Closures with parameters

Tags: java, grails, methods, spring-security, closures

I am upgrading to grails spring security plugin 2.0.0 while upgrading from java 6 to 8. We have so many closures with explicit parameters defined .

eg.

```
@Secured("hasRole(T(com.abc.CommunityPermissions).MANAGE_POSTS)")
    def list = {SearchCommand searchCommand ->
       ....
....
}
```

Since from 2.0.0 we cannot use @Secured annotation in closures, I think I have to convert the clousure to a method.

Can you guide me on this. Specially when clousres have explicit parameters, what to do is not clear! I tried different options but failed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a closure **property** like this:

```
class Controller {
    def list = { SearchCommand searchCommand ->
    }
}
```

To a method, it's just simple syntax change:

```
class Controller {
    def list(SearchCommand searchCommand) {
    }
}
```